# How do i expand a DIVs width depending on a value in SQL Column

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, sql

**What I want to achieve:**
[image: My desired outcome]

So essentially when I upvote a client the green bar will increase and when I down vote the red bar increases.

I currently have it working so that when you up or down vote it submits a value to the database in 2 different columns: *Positive* and *Negative*. In the picture where the bars are, I currently have empty divs.

**So how do I expand the div's based on the number of votes?**

**My clients.php:**

```
<?php

$clientInfo = "SELECT * FROM Clients ORDER BY Client ASC";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $clientInfo);

echo "<div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block;'>";

while ($client = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<div class='clientid' style='height: 50px; font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 100%'>" . 

            "
            <div style='width: 35%;'>
                <div style='color: green;'></div>
            </div>

            <div style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>      
                <span style='font-size: 20px;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-up vote-up'></span>
            </div>" .

                 "<div class='hover-cursor hvr-underline-reveal voteup votedown' data-clientid='{$client['ClientID']}' style='width: 20%; display: inline-block;'>" . $client['Client'] . "</div>" . 

            "<div style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>
                <span style='font-size: 20px; text-align: right;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-down vote-down'></span>
            </div>

            <div style='width: 35%;'>
                <div style='color: red;'></div>
            </div>

         </div> 
        <br />";
}

echo "</div>";

?>
```

Its the two divs with a width of 35% that will be the progress bars.

The columns should show based on a percentage of the total votes, so say there are 4 votes, 3 up 1 down, it shows 75% green, 25% red.

Comment: What's your max amount of votes? What is '100%'? Also - what variables contains the number of votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you should take the positive and negative votes from your database and count the total number of votes.

Then you should find the percentage of both and set the width in you code. Remember to add an "%" and the end so the browser knows you're working with percentage.

If we take your example above, where 1 is down and 3 is up the math look like this:

```
y = (1/4)*100 = 25%
```

Here I have implemented it in your code:

```
$clientInfo = "SELCT * FROM Clients ORDER BY Client ASC";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $clientInfo);

echo "<div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block;'>";

while ($client = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $positive = $client['positive'];
  $negative = $client['negative'];
  $total = ($positive+$negative);

  // Calculate width in percentage
  $positiveWidth = ($positive/$total)*100."%";
  $negativeWidth = ($negative/$total)*100."%";

  // The output
  echo "<div class='clientid' style='height: 50px; font-size: 18px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 100%'>" . 

    "
    <div style='width: $positiveWidth;'>
        <div style='color: green;'></div>
    </div>

    <div style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>      
        <span style='font-size: 20px;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-up vote-up'></span>
    </div>" .

         "<div class='hover-cursor hvr-underline-reveal voteup votedown' data-clientid='{$client['ClientID']}' style='width: 20%; display: inline-block;'>" . $client['Client'] . "</div>" . 

    "<div style='display: inline-block; width: 5%;'>
        <span style='font-size: 20px; text-align: right;' class='hover-cursor fa fa-chevron-down vote-down'></span>
    </div>

    <div style='width: $negativeWidth;'>
        <div style='color: red;'></div>
    </div>

  </div> 
  <br />";
}

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: really appreciate this! I'll give it a go and since its the best answer to poor question i admit ill vote as answer, thank you!